# Composite function derivative/ Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $F(x) = f(g(x))$,  $g(2) = 4$, $g'(2) = 3$, $f'(4) = 5$, what is $F'(2)$?

Please explain how you got the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F'(2)=f'(g(2))\;(g'(2))\; $ by the chain rule, so we have $F'(2)=f'(4)\;g'(2)=(5)(3)=15 $

Recall, this all follows from your definition, $F(x)=f(g(x)),$ so $F'(x)=f'(g(x))\;(g'(x))$ i.e., $F'(2)=f'(g(2))\;(g'(2))=f'(4)\;(3)=15$

Comment: It was that simple ._. . Thanks.

Comment: Yup thats it for this question! No problem